# Disable column reordering in WPF with Style

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml, listview, .net-4.0

I have an application with a lot of `ListView` controls using the `GridView` layout. All of these use a custom `Style` `customStyle`. I want to disable column reordering in all of these `ListView` controls.

Can I do this without touching all of the controls using the existing Style? I tried this, but it doesn't seem to work:

```
<Style x:Key="customStyle"
       BasedOn="{StaticResource ResourceKey={x:Type ListView}}"
       TargetType="{x:Type ListView}">
    <Setter Property="GridView.AllowsColumnReorder" Value="False" />
    ...
</Style>
```

Thanks!

**Update:** If this is not possible, is there a way to disable the column reordering by default in my application?

**Update:**
I also tried this, which doesn't work. Probably because GridView doesn't have a `Style` property.

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type GridView}">
    <Setter Property="AllowsColumnReorder" Value="False" />
    ...
</Style>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this using a attached dependency property for the ListView control. This property will then set the property on the GridView. From my Style I can then set this attached dependency property. Still not a nice solution, but it works.

Answer (score 6):

Here's what you should have done:

In this style definition

```
<Style x:Key="{x:Static GridView.GridViewScrollViewerStyleKey}" TargetType="ScrollViewer">
```

There is a

```
<GridViewHeaderRowPresenter
```

And it has an attribute AllowsColumnReorder
hard code it to false.

...

I know ...
Two year old thread.
But I bet people still read it.

Answer (score 1):

Just simply add this attributes to your datagrid tag

```
CanUserResizeColumns="False"
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1176800/182344).

Try to set default style of all `GridView` in your pages with this property.

**EDIT:** Create new class that inherit from `GridView`. And change value of `AllowsColumnReorder` property in constructor or change default value of dependency property `AllowsColumnReorderProperty` in static constructor to false. And use this class for your list views in all your pages.

**EDIT 2**: The best way to override dependency property - are used [OverrideMetadata](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms597491.aspx) method in static constructor.

I have tired to use something like

`<Setter Property="(ListView.View).(GridView.AllowsColumnReorder)" Value="False"/>`

But it doesn't compile.

Comment: I tried that. However, GridView doesn't has a Style property.

Comment: This is a very ugly solution. Not only do I have to touch every single ListView in the application which is exactly what I wanted to avoid, I also have to create a new kind of GridView only to change a default value. There hast to be anotehr way.

Comment: Agree, it looks not very smart. But I couldn't set child property in `Style` and can't figure out what is wrong.

Comment: And if you _have_ to touch every `ListView`, then it is easier to just do `<GridView AllowsColumnReorder="False">...</GridView>` and be done with it.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove `x:key` in your example, move it to app.xaml, and make it default style for all `GridView` in your app.

Comment: GridView doesn't seem to allow styling in this way.

Comment: You have to check the GridView default template, and find the way through. For getting the template, open in Expression blend, and Click on `Template-> Edit a copy`